# Error while creating entity with relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

First of all, Error is "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

I have two entities User & UsersInHospitals

here is how i create a new account for user

```
var user = new User(); user.UserID = Guid.NewGuid(); user.Address = employmentAddress.Trim(); user.ZipCode = int.Parse(zipcode.Trim());

UsersInHospital hospitalAff;

          hospitalAff = new UsersInHospital()
           {
                    UserID = user.UserID,
                    HospitalID = Guid.Parse(hospitalAff1),
                    IsEmployed = Boolean.Parse(isEmployed1)
           };
           user.UsersInHospitals.Add(hospitalAff);

                hospitalAff = new UsersInHospital()
                {
                    UserID = user.UserID,
                    HospitalID = Guid.Parse(hospitalAff1),
                    IsEmployed = Boolean.Parse(isEmployed2)
                };
                user.UsersInHospitals.Add(hospitalAff);
```

and save it

```
_db.AddToUsers(user);
return _db.SaveChanges(); //THIS LINE GIVES ME ERROR
```

i am using entity framework 4. I doubt that i will have to create variables individually for each hospital entity

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 individual variables for the users in hospital, otherwise you are adding 2 references of the same object to your list, which is why Entity Framework is trying to add IEntityChangeTracker twice to the same object:

```
var user = new User
{
    UserID = Guid.NewGuid(), 
    Address = employmentAddress.Trim(), 
    ZipCode = int.Parse(zipcode.Trim())
};

var hospitalAff1 = new UsersInHospital
{
    UserID = user.UserID,
    HospitalID = Guid.Parse(hospitalAff1),
    IsEmployed = Boolean.Parse(isEmployed1)
};

user.UsersInHospitals.Add(hospitalAff1);

var hospitalAff2 = new UsersInHospital
{
    UserID = user.UserID,
    HospitalID = Guid.Parse(hospitalAff2),
    IsEmployed = Boolean.Parse(isEmployed2)
};

user.UsersInHospitals.Add(hospitalAff2);
```

also, you don't need to specify the UserId in the `UsersInHospital` objects. If you have properly set up your primary and foreign keys, entity framework will do that work for you. Then your code could look like:

```
var user = new User
{
    UserID = Guid.NewGuid(), 
    Address = employmentAddress.Trim(), 
    ZipCode = int.Parse(zipcode.Trim()),
    UsersInHospitals = new List<UsersInHospital> //or array or whatever it is
    {
        new UsersInHospital
        {
            HospitalID = Guid.Parse(hospitalAff1),
            IsEmployed = Boolean.Parse(isEmployed1)
        },
        new UsersInHospital
        {
            HospitalID = Guid.Parse(hospitalAff2),
            IsEmployed = Boolean.Parse(isEmployed2)
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got what was the issue.

Actually i was adding UsersInHospitals with same HospitalID and that was creating problem of duplicate entities

Thanks @Darko for correcting "UserID = user.UserID" as its automatically added by EF.

I have edited my question to actually show the problem. Sorry for not showing this issue in the question